# Django - 'module' object has no attribute 'site'

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-urls

When I try to runserver, it gives me this error. 
Any sample project is running without any issue.

[Trackback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xwrg.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow, please read this to elaborate a better question -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Post the entire error traceback, not just the final error message.

Comment: I've uploaded the trackback screenshot @JohnGordon

Comment: Show us how the `admin` module is defined.  (are you importing it from somewhere?)  Also, providing information via screenshot instead of plain text makes it harder for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I've solved the issue. Just Invalidated caches and restarted pyCharm

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it.
Just did : "Invalidate caches/restart" and it worked fine.
Thanks to everyone who spared their valuable time.